# How can I get the interests of my friend through facebook api?

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook

I am new to facebook api, and want to integrate in an site of my client. I have codeigniter as my MVC.It would be great if some one could tell me which library to use for facebook connect, and as to how to get interests of a friend who is in my friend list.

Comment: I am not sure if you can show a specific persons activity feed, but you might start by reading the Facebook API http://bit.ly/nI2TVg

Comment: Sorry, you may wish to stat here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ask for the `user_interests` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). Then make an [authenticated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) [Graph API](https://graph.facebook.com/) call to [`/me/interests`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/interests).

Comment: Would this not return your own interests?  If so, why is this accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is description how to implement the facebook lib in CI:
http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/

From there, you can connect with facebook and retrieve data.