# How to get user Interests?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

This is not a duplicate of [How can I get the interests of my friend through facebook api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587373/how-can-i-get-the-interests-of-my-friend-through-facebook-api). `user_interests` permission (to access `/me/interests`) is useless (if not deprecated) Facebook feature that hardly ever returns any data.

Instead, I am referring to the data aggregated by Facebook at this page:

[image]

These are all user likes grouped into categories like "Music", "Books", "TV Shows", etc. Generally, user likes can be retrieved through `/me/likes`. However, the latter query returns a rather [vivid array of categories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845336/368691).

Is there a way to get user likes categorised into the same generic categories like Facebook does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/:

> The User object has the following *connections*:
>
> books: The books listed on the user's profile.
>
> games: Games the user has added to the Arts and Entertainment section of their profile.
>
> movies: The movies listed on the user's profile.
>
> music: The music listed on the user's profile.
>
> television: The television listed on the user's profile.

---

The *fields* `favorite_athletes` and `favorite_teams` are deprecated, though. Not sure, if there will be any replacement for these analog to the above connections – or if users are just supposed to normally “like” the fan pages of athletes/teams in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this issue is to process the API data within my application as such:

```
'Books' => array('Fictional Character', 'Writer', 'Book', 'Author', 'Book Store', 'Library', 'Magazine'),
'Films' => array('Actor/Director', 'Movie', 'Producer', 'Studio', 'Movie Theater', 'TV/Movie Award', 'Fictional Character', 'Movies/Music'),
[..]
```

e.g., if user likes "Writer" or "Book", I assign the like to "Books" category.

However, this solution is not ideal as Facebook might change category names, add new names, etc.